# Caffeine cache and security across many users

Tags: caching, caffeine-cache

I know very little how cache and how Caffeine work, but I want to use it to resolve following performance issue.

Let's say I have some simple method without parameters in "Service A" which call some other "Service B", map returned List of InputObject into List of OutputObject and returns this List of OutputObject to controller.

All security between web app and backend services rely on jwt tokens.

This call from Service A to B takes a lot of time, returns many elements in List and all have to be mapped to another object first before sending them to web app.

How standard configuration (TTL - 60 seconds) with annotation @Cacheable("result") on public method List getMappedObjects() will behave in case many users are calling same method? Each of user will be received a different list of sensitive data. All data should be cached in a secure way, not shared across users by accident.

For the moment I did't found any describtion/solution concerning this problem.

Comment: Caffeine is a `ConcurrentHashMap` with an automatic removal based on a policy. Ensuring that you secure data, such as by using keys qualified by that user, are application concerns far above that of a hash map, list, or binary tree. It sounds like your question should be directed at towards how to use Spring securely, which is a great topic to explore if you reorient this question towards that community.